# Xcode duplicating simulators 10s of times

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time I start Xcode I seem to get dozens of duplicate simulators populating my damn simulator menu. I have no idea why its happening or how to stop it, but its only getting worse over time. I've tried deleting the simulator folder from both the Application folder and the cache folder to no avail. This is getting super tedious and slow to have to delete 10-20 different versions of every single one of my simulators every time, its a good 10-15 minute time waster.

Does anyone have any idea, at all, of how to stop this issue?

Comment: I've had this problem from time to time. No idea what the cause is but I would love to know.

Comment: does this happens also after a reboot for instance? And what happens if you try to start the simulator alone?

Comment: It seems to happen every time I go from beta version to the stable version, and it repopulates with dozens of additional 8.4 simulators, as well as for the Resizable iPhone and iPad it populates with dozens of extra 8.2 as well.

Comment: I have 8 of each simulator at this point. :) _Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)_

Comment: Just counted... I'm at 10 of each one running iOS 8.4